# Adding Python Modules on A2hosting Web Server

Tags: python, web-services, web, ssh, matplotlib

I am a newb so sorry in advance.

**Background:** I am currently using A2hosting as my web server. I have python on the web server (obviously), that I use to dynamically update my website by a cronjob. Now, I would like to make plots of stuff and add them to my website using the Python module matplotlib. I currently, do not have that module on the webserver, or at least I am getting the error that no module exists.

**Question:** So how do I add a Python module when I have SSH'd into my A2hosting webserver? I tried using sudo apt get but did not work.

**My Error Message:**

```
roy123@reichwein.net [~]# pip install numpy
Downloading/unpacking numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.8.0.tar.gz (3.8Mb): 3.8Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package numpy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in ?
      File "/home/roy123/build/numpy/setup.py", line 16
        from __future__ import division, print_function
    SyntaxError: future feature print_function is not defined
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in ?

  File "/home/roy123/build/numpy/setup.py", line 16

    from __future__ import division, print_function

SyntaxError: future feature print_function is not defined

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/roy123/build/numpy
Storing complete log in /home/roy123/.pip/pip.log
```

Thanks!

Comment: `but did not work` - that's hardly any details to debug. What error did you face when you tried installing it? We need details to solve problem.

Comment: Good point. Let me try it again and I will update question.

Comment: @Bibhas Apparently it didn't work, however it did add a .pip directory to my root directory. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Which version of python do you have installed?

Comment: Hi there! Did you result this problem? @jerk_dadt